# How to center input-group inside a div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to center the `.input-group` inside a `<div>`. When I use the class `center-block`, the `<span>` takes the full width and pushes down the input field below it. I want to center them together.

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="input-group input-group-lg inv-amount-block">
         <span class="input-group-addon" id="inv-rs">Rs</span>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
     </div>
 </div>
```

I want to center them together like how they are by default.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/68pu5hez/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change the display property in the `CSS` for the `.center-block`

Edited: Difference between `display: block` and `display: table` is that - . `display: block` - will extend to 100% of the available space, while `display: table` -  will only be as wide as its contents.

So in the latter case your `span` and `input field` would only be as wide as its content and won't take up the entire `40%` width that is specified.

```css
.center-block {
    display: table;  /* Instead of display:block */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
              <div class = "col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">

                <div class="input-group input-group-lg inv-amount-block center-block ">
                  <span class="input-group-addon " id="inv-rs">Rs</span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                </div>
               
              </div><br>
              
                            <div class = "col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">

                <div class="input-group input-group-lg inv-amount-block ">
                  <span class="input-group-addon " id="inv-rs">Rs</span>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Amount" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                </div>
               
              </div>
```

Comment: a bit of explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 9):

In **Bootstrap 4**, `center-block` has been replaced by `mx-auto`, and input-group has changed to `display:flex`. Here's how to center in Bootstrap 4...

```
     <div class="col-12">
          <div class="input-group input-group-lg w-25 mx-auto">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Rs</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Amount">
          </div>
    </div>
```

Remember that `input-group` will fill the width of the parent, so in this case I added `w-25` (width:25%) to demonstrate the centering.

[Demo on Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/XyAOgpFfly)

Answer (score 1):

**Copy below code and paste in your file and run check this input box is align center and responsive also.**

**This example is based in bootstrap v3.4**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Center Input box demo</title>
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <form class="row" action="" method="post" id="search_project_form">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-offset-2">
        <input type="text" name="search_group" id="search_group" class="form-control" placeholder="Group Number" required>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download Data</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display: grid for input-group-text element.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="form-floating" style="width: 85%;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="abc" placeholder="Description">
        <label for="abc">Description</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-text" style="display: grid; width: 15%;">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I found for this type of problem.

```
....
<div class="input-group mb-3" style="margin-left:calc(50% - 80px);">
    <span class="input-group-text">Rec ID:</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  value="" />
</div>
....
```

I calculate the left margin. **80px** is **half the width** of the object